# How to access a file in an external path in Java Web Application?

Tags: java, string, path

I have a `DSSBean` in the folder `beans` on this position:

```
workspace3 - p1\DSS-jar\build\classes\beans
```

In the same workspace, I have a different project, and in that project I have a javascript file (in folder `js`)

```
workspace3 - p1\DSS-war\WebContent\js
```

Now I need to call that file in a function, that takes a string as a parameter, that string is the path to the folder... But I have no idea how to do it (I hard coded a absolute path)

```
String s = "C:\\Users\\...\\workspace3 - p1\\DSS-war\\WebContent\\js\\boot.js";
```

Is there a way not to call it from the actual position, but somehow from the workspace within?

I tryed already this:

```
s = "\\..\\..\\..\\..\\DSS-war\\WebContent\\js\\boot.js";
```

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path ? Is this a web application or a stand alone Java program ?

Comment: its a web aplication....and i have not used a relative path bc i dont know how

Comment: Maybe this helps you understand how it works http://superuser.com/a/644421

Comment: i belive its not the way for me....mby somethink like ../../ or the like?

Comment: so i dont need a shortcut...i need a real path to take them....